# trace identities for the functional calculus

Tags: operator-algebras, matrix-calculus

I'm sorry if this is a trivial question, but I cannot convince myself of why $\text{Tr}\,f(EFE)=\text{Tr}\,f(FEF)$ for projections $E$ and $F$ on a Hilbert space and a (say, continuous or Borel) function $f.$
Thank your for your help!

Comment: Does $\text{Tr}(AB) = \text{Tr}(BA)$ sill hold when $A,B$ are operators on a Hilbert space? If so, then $\text{Tr}(EFE) = \text{Tr}(EEF) = \text{Tr}(EF)$ and $\text{Tr}(FEF) = \text{Tr}(EFF) = \text{Tr}(EF)$.

Comment: Yes, but the equation in question has $f$'s in it.

Comment: Well for continuous functions $f$ couldn't you approximate with polynomials? The elements are self-adjoint and, for example, the squaring function would have 

$Tr((EFE)^2) = Tr(E \cdot FEFE) = Tr(FEFE \cdot E) = Tr(FEFE)$

and 

$Tr( (FEF)^2) = Tr( FE \cdot FEF) = Tr(FEF \cdot FE) = Tr(FEFE)$

The result should follow from an inductive proof for higher orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding upon the comment by @JimmyK4542 .

Let $X=EFE$ and $Y=FEF$, then 
$$ \eqalign {
\rm{tr}(X^k) &= \rm{tr}((EF)^kE) \cr
  &= \rm{tr}(E(EF)^k) \cr
  &= \rm{tr}((EF)^k) \cr
  &= \rm{tr}((FE)^k) \cr
  &= \rm{tr}(Y^k) \cr
} $$
Now expand the function as a Taylor series and take its trace
$$ \eqalign {
\rm{tr}(\rm{f}(X)) &= \rm{tr}\bigg(\sum^n_{k=0} c_k X^k\bigg) \cr
   &= \sum^n_{k=0} c_k \rm{tr}(X^k) \cr
   &= \sum^n_{k=0} c_k \rm{tr}(Y^k) \cr
   &= \rm{tr}(\rm{f}(Y)) \cr
} $$

Comment: I think one should rather invoke the Stone-Weierstrass theorem than Taylor series expansion when $f$ is a continuous function